# Subject field from Recycle bin

Tags: soql, workbench

I have a full recycle bin (which is currently good) as I need to see if there is a specific case to restore. Unfortunately I only see the case number which is pretty useless.
Is there an easy way to get at least a list with additional fields for the items in the recycle bin? I tried the workbench but it only shows me active cases when I try this:

`SELECT CaseNumber, Subject, LastModifiedDate FROM Case ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC NULLS FIRST`

and the filter is IsDeleted = True

KR Alex

Comment: Did you also by any chance checked "Include Deleted and Archived Records" in workbench?

Comment: @kurunve Yes. But I also activated Bulk CSV because I wanted to export it. Then I got this error message: Including deleted and archived records not supported by Bulk Queries. It works with the normal list-view

Comment: You will have to use some other tool like Jetstream or Data Loader so you can't do the soql query with ALL RECORDS clause and export the results

Comment: @DavidCheng Can´t thank you enough for Jetstream. This tool is awesome so far. Got all I needed.